# MySQL database "borrow limit"

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do i setup borrow limit to books in SQL commmand?

- teachers - max 5 books
- students - max 2 books
- professors - max 3 books

Comment: Perhaps a trigger based solution?

Comment: What is a "borrow limit"? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can use limit in your query e.g

```
select a,b,c from table where condition='' order by a ASC limit 3
```

Comment: Can you explain further how that works? How does it solve the vague requirement "teachers- max 5 books"?